# How to specify expiry to a (css/js) files of a website in a shared hosting?

Tags: html, shared-hosting, expires

I have read the other answers but all are based on editing the .htaccess file.
Is there any way to set expiry without touching the .htaccess file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is possible using Apache and PHP, by setting the expires and cache-control using [header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php), you can find out more about what is, and what is not supported in the [HTTP/1.1 specification](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2616.html). PHP headers will look something like this:

```
$seconds_to_cache = 3600;
$ts = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time() + $seconds_to_cache) . " GMT";
header("Expires: $ts");
header("Pragma: cache");
header("Cache-Control: max-age=$seconds_to_cache");
```

You can find more help in regards of setting up [PHP headers on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=PHP%20header), here's a just few to get you started:

- [Setting up Expire Headers with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776971/setting-up-expire-headers-with-php).
- [PHP Header expires not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12935560/php-header-expires-not-working)
- [PHP header expire every day at X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227664/php-header-expire-every-day-at-x)
- [CSS PHP expire problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205336/css-cache-problem)
- [Set expire headers through PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25246811/set-expire-headers-through-php)